# IFS and IFError nesting

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to nest formulas and cant seem to resolve my issue with solutions from other postings. I would like my formula to search a cell and if blank, return a blank...if the referenced cell has a number, return an "iferror" result

For example in the below I would like cell "W2" to return a blank as "S2" is blank. If "S2" were to have any numeric value, it would populate the calculated variance in "W2" (i.e. =IFERROR((P51-P50)/P50,0))

[image]

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.  Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=ifs( 
  isblank(S2), iferror(1/0), 
  isnumber(S2), iferror( (P51-P50) / P50, 0 ), 
  true, na() 
)
```